# textbox is not displayed when I use integer as field type in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am using integer type for a field in form type of Symfony2. My code is as follows:

```
$builder->add('phoneNumber', 'integer',array(
                'required'      => true,
                'constraints' => array(
                     'pattern' => '/^[0-9]\d*$/',
                      new Length(array(
                         'min'   => 10,
                         'max'   => 20
                               ))
         )));
```

Although phone number field is validated, a uparrow and downarrow is displayed and if I click on it I am getting numbers from -1 instead of textbox. If I put number as field type then textbox is dispayed but the field is not validated. I would be grateful if someone could help me out with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting the min and max in the attributes like `'attr' => array('min' => 10, 'max' => 20))`.

Comment: I think your regex pattern is redundant? If you truly only want numbers then an integer type will give you that. Also, I think you only need [0-9] or \d in your pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`integer` fields aren't used very often (only for literal integers, and even then not always). For a phone number you'd definitely want a `text` field.

**Update**

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;

$builder->add('phoneNumber', 'text', array(
    'required' => true,
    'constraints' => array(
        new Regex(array(
            'pattern' => '/^[0-9]*$/'
        )) ,
        new Length(array(
            'min' => 10,
            'max' => 20
        ))
    )
));
```

@Rufinus's answer may be a better option.

Comment: Eventhough If I  use text as my input field, My regular expression is not validated. The regex is validated only if I put integer as my input field. So can anyone tell me how to use integer field type exactly.

Comment: Your constraints shouldn't be affected by the form type you use, because they are typically run against the model data after the form is bound. So the Regex constraint should work for any non-compound field.

Comment: the code you gave me worked.Thanks alot. But I want to know how error message is diaplayed when the entered value in the textbox does not match with the regex for each particular field.

Comment: I think you want the 'message' parameter for the Regex type http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html#message

Comment: I tried using the 'message' parameter also. It didn't work. I want to set my error message in the form type. So could you please suggest me how to set the error message. Thanks in advance.,

Comment: What message are you currently seeing?

Comment: Now I am not getting any message for invalid phone number. But If I submit the form, the form is not submitted as the regex of the phoneNumber does not match with the entered input for phoneNumber field. What and how  should I write code to get the message for Invalid phoneNumber. Could you please help me with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can try setting htmlPattern to null, which should prevent the pattern from being converted into an HTML5 form validation.

Comment: But then how should I validate my htmlpattern if I set it to  null.

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean. Is an HTML5 validation issue?

Comment: Yes. It is a validation issue only. Can you please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

use the `number` field. see http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html

or for all available form types:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html